# Why is typescript array reacting differently?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find value exists in the array of object User.

```
isInArray(elements) {
        console.log(elements)
        console.log(elements[0])
/** extra check **/ 
    }
```

output

```
[{"id":"10208613798364187"}]
[
```

Should output be

```
[{"id":"10208613798364187"}]
{"id":"10208613798364187"}
```

I am not sure if `ts.config` is required to help me:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Seems unlikely. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: That just means that what you think is an array of objects is in fact a string.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer exactly. will try.

Comment: @JBNizet i also assumed it to be. I tried JSON.parse it failed!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer its working in Plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:qvZ8Iri6jRUioBEDsa32?p=preview

Comment: Is it possible you didn't save all changes? If the question is about Angular 1.x please use the `angularjs` tag. `angular` is for Angular >= 2.0.0

Comment: oh no. I found the issue. It was when i was updating my array object and uploading on server. the format got messed there.

Comment: how can i close this question?

Comment: @User1911 There is no "close" concept in stackoverflow. You can either delete the question, or add an answer yourself and mark as answered or simply do nothing.

Comment: If you examine `elements` in the devtools console, you will see that it is displayed as `"[{"id":"10208613798364187"}]"`. Note carefully the quotation marks at the beginning and end. That means that it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output:

```
[{"id":"10208613798364187"}] // elements
[                            // elements[0]
```

elements is clearly a `string`.

## Fix

Use `JSON.parse` to convert to an array.